# R: generate new var based on index numbers [i] within input var name

Tags: r, date, data.table, dplyr

I have a data set with a series of dates for each id. I have generated a series of lead and lag variables, and now I want to generate another set of variables with the difference in days between the lead and lag variables across each row. When I generated the lead and lag variables, I used paste0 to attach a number to each variable name. For example, the lag variables are named prev_date1:prev_date20. I wanted to be able to use these numbers in generating another set of variables to calculate the difference in days between pairs. The general form is given by:
`diff2prev[i] = prev_date[i-1] - prev_date[i]`

I can't work out how to implement this in practice though. In my initial approach, I had only 7 variables and wrote them out separately (sample code for this included), but now I need to generate more than 7 so would like to find a more efficient way to do this. I have tried using data.table and dplyr as shown in the examples, but none are working so far. Any pointers about where I am going wrong and how to improve my code would be much appreciated.

```
if (!require('pacman')) install.packages('pacman'); library(pacman) 
#> Loading required package: pacman
p_load("dplyr", "lubridate","tidyverse")

id <- c(13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15)

date <- c("2017-06-06", "2017-07-26", "2017-09-22", "2017-10-21", "2018-03-29", "2018-03-29", "2018-03-29", "2018-03-29", "2018-03-29", "2018-03-29", "2018-03-29", "2018-03-29", "2018-03-29", "2018-03-29", "2018-03-29", "2019-05-12", "2019-06-07", "2019-10-08","2016-10-20", "2016-10-20", "2016-10-20", "2016-10-20", "2018-01-06", "2018-01-06", "2018-01-06", "2018-01-06", "2018-01-06","2018-01-06", "2018-05-02", "2018-08-04", "2018-08-04", "2018-08-04", "2018-11-22", "2018-12-26", "2018-12-26", "2018-12-26", "2018-12-26", "2018-12-26", "2018-12-26", "2018-12-26", "2018-12-26", "2018-12-26", "2018-12-26", "2018-12-26", "2019-05-11","2019-06-04", "2019-11-18", "2016-04-01", "2018-04-04", "2019-04-03", "2019-04-04", "2019-04-04", "2019-04-04", "2019-04-04","2019-04-04", "2019-04-04", "2019-04-04", "2019-04-04", "2019-04-04", "2019-04-04", "2019-04-04", "2019-06-03", "2019-06-04", "2019-11-23")

sample <- bind_cols(id, date)
#> New names:
#> * NA -> ...1
#> * NA -> ...2

colnames <- c("id", "date")

names(sample) <- colnames

sample <- sample %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(date = as_date(date))

#Using data.table shift/lag to create 20 prev dates

sample[,paste0('prev_date', 1:20) := shift(date, 1:20, type="lag"), by = id][]


#Using data.table shift/lead to create 20 prev dates
       
sample[,paste0('next_date', 1:20) := shift(date, 1:20, type="lead"), by = id][]
```

Here is what I have tried so far

```
## Dplyr approach to writing out each new variable
##This works but seems inefficient
sample <- sample %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(diff2prev = date - prev_date,
       diff2prev1 = prev_date - prev_date1,
       diff2prev2 = prev_date1 - prev_date2,
       diff2prev3 = prev_date2 - prev_date3,
       diff2prev4 = prev_date3 - prev_date4,
       diff2prev5 = prev_date4 - prev_date5,
       diff2prev6 = prev_date5 - prev_date6,
       diff2prev7 = prev_date6 - prev_date7,
       diff2next = next_date - date,
       diff2next1 = next_date1 - next_date,
       diff2next2 = next_date2 - next_date1,
       diff2next3 = next_date3 - next_date2,
       diff2next4 = next_date4 - next_date3,
       diff2next5 = next_date5 - next_date4,
       diff2next6 = next_date6 - next_date5,
       diff2next7 = next_date7 - next_date6)

##Attempt at using data.table to generate variables but not sure how to incorporate the length of [i] for iteration
setDT(pid_ell)[,paste0('diff2prev', 1:20) := (diff2prev[i] = prev_date[i-1] - prev_date[i], 1:20), by = id][]

##Attempt to create a function that would create the new empty variables and then fill them in
#function to create variable calculating the difference in days to the previous date
fn_diff2prev <- function(date, prev_date) {
  for (i in 2:lead_lag){
    diff2prev[i] <- paste0('diff2prev', 1:20) # new var names
  }
    diff2prev1 <- date - prev_date1 #first one calculates from date
  for (i in 2:lead_lag){
    diff2prev[i] <- prev_date[i-1] - prev_date[i] #others calculate based on [i]
  }
    return
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you've done well to get the structure of the `sample` data.table setup ok. You've missed out `library(data.table)` & `setDT(sample)` in your example but I assume it has to be a `data.table` else the `shift` functions won't work. I would keep the setting of the difference simple and use a loop. I'd use the `data.table::set` function as it makes these loop operations quite simple eg

```
N <- 20
# define the column you want to set and the x & y such that the difference
# is x - y
ncols <- paste0("diff2prev", 1:N)
x_cols <- c("date", paste0("prev_date", 1:(N-1)))
y_cols <- paste0("prev_date", 1:N)

#eg
ncols[4]
x_cols[4]
y_cols[4]

# loop and use data.table set
for(i in 1:N){
  set(sample,
      j = ncols[i],
      value = sample[[x_cols[i]]] - sample[[y_cols[i]]])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just calculate `diff(date)` and then `shift`?

```
sample[,c(paste0('date2prev', 1:20), paste0('date2next', 1:20)) := {
  days = c(NA, diff(date))
  c(shift(days, 0:19), shift(days, -1:-20)) 
}, by = id]
```

Here is an overview of the output

```
    id prev_date2 prev_date1       date next_date1 next_date2 date2prev1 date2prev2 date2next1 date2next2
 1: 13       <NA>       <NA> 2017-06-06 2017-07-26 2017-09-22         NA         NA         50         58
 2: 13       <NA> 2017-06-06 2017-07-26 2017-09-22 2017-10-21         50         NA         58         29
 3: 13 2017-06-06 2017-07-26 2017-09-22 2017-10-21 2018-03-29         58         50         29        159
 4: 13 2017-07-26 2017-09-22 2017-10-21 2018-03-29 2018-03-29         29         58        159          0
 5: 13 2017-09-22 2017-10-21 2018-03-29 2018-03-29 2018-03-29        159         29          0          0
 6: 13 2017-10-21 2018-03-29 2018-03-29 2018-03-29 2018-03-29          0        159          0          0
 7: 13 2018-03-29 2018-03-29 2018-03-29 2018-03-29 2018-03-29          0          0          0          0
 8: 13 2018-03-29 2018-03-29 2018-03-29 2018-03-29 2018-03-29          0          0          0          0
 9: 13 2018-03-29 2018-03-29 2018-03-29 2018-03-29 2018-03-29          0          0          0          0
10: 13 2018-03-29 2018-03-29 2018-03-29 2018-03-29 2018-03-29          0          0          0          0
11: 13 2018-03-29 2018-03-29 2018-03-29 2018-03-29 2018-03-29          0          0          0          0
12: 13 2018-03-29 2018-03-29 2018-03-29 2018-03-29 2018-03-29          0          0          0          0
13: 13 2018-03-29 2018-03-29 2018-03-29 2018-03-29 2018-03-29          0          0          0          0
14: 13 2018-03-29 2018-03-29 2018-03-29 2018-03-29 2019-05-12          0          0          0        409
15: 13 2018-03-29 2018-03-29 2018-03-29 2019-05-12 2019-06-07          0          0        409         26
16: 13 2018-03-29 2018-03-29 2019-05-12 2019-06-07 2019-10-08        409          0         26        123
17: 13 2018-03-29 2019-05-12 2019-06-07 2019-10-08       <NA>         26        409        123         NA
18: 13 2019-05-12 2019-06-07 2019-10-08       <NA>       <NA>        123         26         NA         NA
19: 14       <NA>       <NA> 2016-10-20 2016-10-20 2016-10-20         NA         NA          0          0
20: 14       <NA> 2016-10-20 2016-10-20 2016-10-20 2016-10-20          0         NA          0          0
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a vectorised operation so you could create variables that you want to subtract and then subtract two equal sized dataframes.

```
library(data.table)
#Create data.table
sample <- data.table(id, date)
#Create next and previous dates
sample[,paste0('prev_date', 1:5) := shift(date, 1:5, type="lag"), by = id][]
sample[,paste0('next_date', 1:5) := shift(date, 1:5, type="lag"), by = id][]

#Create vectors of next and previous column names along with "date" column
p1 <- c('date', grep('prev_date', names(sample), value = TRUE))
n1 <- c('date', grep('next_date', names(sample), value = TRUE))

#Create new columns for the dataframe
new_p1 <- paste0('new_prev', seq_along(p1[-1]))
new_n1 <- paste0('new_next', seq_along(n1[-1]))

#Convert to dataframe
setDF(sample)

#Perform subtract of the columns. 
sample[new_p1] <- sample[p1[-length(p1)]] - sample[p1[-1]]
sample[new_n1] <- sample[n1[-1]] - sample[n1[-length(n1)]]
sample
```